# typeError: not all arguments convereted during string formatting

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, typeerror, output-formatting

I have a function as follows (I am working on python2.7):

```
def ip_split(ip):

    rtr, mask = cidr.split('/')                                                  
    ip = ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(rtr))                                      
    if ip.version == 4:                                                          
        n = ipaddress.IPv4Network(unicode(cidr), strict=False)                   
    else:                                                                        
        n = ipaddress.IPv6Network(unicode(cidr), strict=False)                   
    first, last = n[2], n[-2]                                                    
    return n, first, last, n[1], n.network_address, mask 

n_sub = "%s/%s" % ip_split('10.10.128.1/18')[3:]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 18, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I am getting the typeError: not all arguments convereted during string formatting.

What can be wrong over here??

Comment: Well `ip_split` returns a 6-tuple. So that means `ip_split(..)[3:]` returns a 3-tuple, whereas there are only two `%s`s in the format string.

Comment: `[3:]` returns `n[1], n.network_address, mask `, but you only provided two targets for string formatting in `"%s/%s" % ip_split('10.10.128.1/18')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ip_split` function returns a 6-tuple. If you use the `[3:]` slice operator, you will obtain everything from index `3` and further, so that will be a 3-tuple.

But your formatting string `'%s/%s'` has only two `%s`s, so Python gets confused. You can (probably) fix it with slicing from index four, so `[4:]`.

A second problem is that `%` takes precedence over indexing, so it sees the expression as `('%s/%s' % ip_split('10.10.128.1/18'))[3:]`, whereas I think you want to first get the last two items of the tuple. The fact that you uses spaces here does not makes a difference (yes, for scoping, Python takes spaces into account, but not for operator precedence).

Alternatively, you can use `[-2:]`, which is closer to "the last two items". So:

```
n_sub = "%s/%s" % (ip_split('10.10.128.1/18')[-2:])
```